# Python selenium ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to login to beeradvocate.com to scrape (crawl) some beer data.
I tried with selenium but have been brutally failing.

here is the html

```
<input type="text" name="login" value="" id="ctrl_pageLogin_login" class="textCtrl" tabindex="1" autofocus="autofocus" style="background-image: url(&quot;data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR4nGP6zwAAAgcBApocMXEAAAAASUVORK5CYII=&quot;); cursor: auto;">
```

i tried using name and value and class but everything has failed. 
I attempted Xpath as my final try, but have failed as well.

[website and inspection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TpoDt.png)

My code:

```
driver=webdriver.Chrome("~~~~\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.beeradvocate.com/community/login/")

from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

driver.maximize_window()

    while True:
        try: 
            WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="ctrl_pageLogin_login"]'))).send_keys("scentmaster")
            break
        except TimeoutException: 
            print("too much time")
```

I've made the button work with:

```
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="pageLogin"]/dl[3]/dd/input')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
```

However, I need to be able to perform sent_keys to type in id and pw to log in...
Anybody got some idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 fields on the page if you use xpath `//*[@id = "ctrl_pageLogin_login"]`, the `input` field you are referring to is the second. Sadly, the selenium **`find element`** by default refers to the first. It will work if you make it like this: `(//*[@id = "ctrl_pageLogin_login"])[2]`.

But I have another suggestion, try to locate element by css selector with this value : `form#pageLogin input#ctrl_pageLogin_login`

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'form#pageLogin input#ctrl_pageLogin_login'))).send_keys("scentmaster")

#for password
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('form#pageLogin input#ctrl_pageLogin_password').send_keys('your_password')

#for submit
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('form#pageLogin input[type=submit]').click()
```

Comment: worked perfectly for me. Thank you very much for solving my problem.

Answer (score 0):

To feed the username, try this xpath:

```
'//form/dl/dd/input[@id="ctrl_pageLogin_login"]'
```

for the password:

```
'//form/dl/dd/input[@id="ctrl_pageLogin_password"]'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'form#pageLogin input#ctrl_pageLogin_login'))).send_keys("scentmaster")

#for password
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('form#pageLogin input#ctrl_pageLogin_password').send_keys('your_password')

#for submit
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('form#pageLogin input[type=submit]').click()
```

The solution above given by frianH worked! :)